# c++ - Init const class members, error: declaration does not declare anything

Tags: c++

I'm trying to initialize const member variables in the member initialization list of the constructor.

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
    const uint32_t LEDS
          ^
```

My code:

```
#include <unistd.h>

class BaseAddr {
public:
    BaseAddr():
        LEDS      (0x41200000),
        SW1       (0x41210000), // switch 1
        SW2       (0x41220000), // switch 2
        AXI_BRAM  (0x40000000), // 128 registers
        AXI_DUMMY (0x43c00000)  // 16 registers, 4 lsb are connected with leds
    { /* nop */ }

    virtual ~BaseAddr() {}

    const uint32_t LEDS;
    const uint32_t SW1;
    const uint32_t SW2;

private:
    const uint32_t AXI_BRAM;
    const uint32_t AXI_DUMMY;
};
```

why is it giving this error?

Comment: which compiler is that? have you defined type `uint32_t`?

Comment: I guess it decays to `const LEDS;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to say you have a macro `LEDS` somewhere defined as follows:

```
#define LEDS
```

Now your member declaration becomes:

```
const uint32_t;
```

This correctly triggers the error, as shown [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2a7960c60404efa).

Comment: You are correct, I'm including this file a file called Leds.h, hence this is where I do #ifndef LEDS #define LEDS

Comment: @GiovanniMacciocu, That would do it. Typically, include guards include the project, the file's name, and possibly more, along with something like `_H` or `_INCLUDED` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Its because header file is not included for uint32_t.

Use any of following header file stdint.h or cstdint